# xcode warns 'no method found' for super class properties

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have a class like this

```
@interface MyParentClass : NSObject {
    NSString *objectName_;
}
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *objectName;
@end
```

and in implementation, I have this:

```
@implementation MyParentClass
@synthesize objectName = objectName_;
@end
```

then I have a child class that inherits from `MyParentClass` like this

```
@interface MyChildClass : MyParentClass {
}
@end
```

the problem is that if I create a child class object and try to access the `objectName` property, it gives me a `no method found` warning i.e.

```
MyChildClass *obj = [[MyChildClass alloc] init];
[obj setObjectName:@"BuzzLightYear"]; // this line produces no method 
                                      // setObjectName found warning
```

how can I remove it?

Answer (score 0):

oops. just realized I had forgotten to `#import "MyChildClass.h"` in the file where I was using the buggy code. adding the `import` fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.It has been solved by `#import MyParentClass.h`.